# Colored Dots :before and :after h2

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to put colored dots before and after h2.

This is my CSS;

```
h2:after {
 width:10px;
 height:10px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background: #b83b3b;
}

h2:after {
 width:10px;
 height:10px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background: #b83b3b;
}
```

But no dots show up.

Any leads?

Thanks!

Jaeeun

Comment: What kind of colored dots? Like "..." ?

Comment: use this `content:'.'` property.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Specify a value for the `content` property, and then add `display:inline-block`

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/T652B/1/)

```
h2:after, h2:before {
    content:"\A";
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: #b83b3b;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You can specify an empty string - it does not have to consist of whitespace (although the whitespace will be collapsed anyway if it's the only content). When you neglect to specify a value `content`, the initial value used is `none`, which is like a null value and therefore distinct from an empty string.

Answer (score 8):

I just want to add an alternative way that I am using - it's a different take on Josh's answer that uses an actual dot character, which allows you to use text-shadow and other text styles if you wish. I think it's also easier to vertically center (in my opinion). I've added on a text-shadow to add a nice glow effect as I'm using it to indicate status.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lde7o8zw/)

```
h2:after, h2:before {
    content: "•";
    color: #b83b3b;
    text-shadow: #b83b3b 0 0 5px;
    margin:0 10px;
}
```